# Adding value to output value

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up my php script to add to a value to the previous value that is returned in the loop. Below is an example. The number on the left is the number that comes from the loop and is returned as `$axle`. The number on the right is the total as is the number from above added to the number on the right '$totalAxle'. I tried a few examples that I found online but they did not seem to work for me. My latest attempt which is the code below resulted in an error Notice: Array to string conversion

6/6

6/12

4/16

```
echo "<td>";

    $axle = "Not Found!";
    foreach ($railunit->railUnit as $ru) {
        if((string)$ru->rvXMLfilename == $rvXMLfilename){
            $axle = (string)$ru->axleCount;
            $array = array("axle" => $axle);
            $axleTotal = array();
            $i = 1;
            $previous = 0;
            foreach($array as $key => $val) {
            $axleTotal['number'.$i] = $val+$previous;
             $previous += $val;
             $i++;   
            };
        }

    }
    echo $axle, "/", $axleTotal;
    echo "</td>";
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your desired output it, could you clarify?

Comment: the first for loop returns a number from an xml file its variable is $axle. Im looking to have that value added the next value passed in the loop let's call that $axleTotal. So for example say the first loop returns $axle returns 6 so $axleTotal would only be 6. The next run of the loop $axle returns 4 so $axleTotal would be 10

Comment: Try: `$axleTotal = $axleTotal + $axle;` in your loop and `$axleTotal = 0;` outside of it.

Comment: Is that the only usage of these loops? To count the total of `$axle` or does it do something else also?

Comment: Only the second loop, the first loop compares data from 2 xml files and if a text string matches it outputs data from it.

Comment: Check my answer below and tell me if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that your `foreach` could be way simpler. I was able to solve it together with OP after a discussion in chat.

```
// add $total = 0; OUTSIDE of any loops so it doesnt get overwritten
$total = 0;

foreach($railunit->railUnit as $ru) {
    $axle = $ru->axleCount;

    $total = $total + $axle;
}


echo $axle . "/" . $total;
```

Comment: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: Try now, I added `array();`

Comment: Edited again, one question: Which datatype is `$axle` in your XML file, should be an integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183395/discussion-between-david-and-rpm192).